# How do I connect a "related products" table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following tables

**products table**

```
product_id
name
desc
```

with a **has many** relation to

**suggested products table**

```
id
product_id
suggested_product_id
Quantity
required (boolean)
```

What I am trying to accomplish is being able to access **the name of a suggested product id** in my view.

**Products Controller**

```
public function show($id)
{
$product = Product::with('stockitems','suggestedproducts.product')->find($id);

  return view('backend.products.show', compact('product'));
}
```

I know the issue is at "suggestedproducts.product" just not sure how i specify the key(suggested_product_id) for the eager load is a product_id.

Comment: *I know the issue is at "suggestedproducts.product" just not sure how i specify the key for the eager load is a product_id.* -- use [constrained eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads). i mean, ie. `Product::with(['stockitems','suggestedproducts.product' => function($query){ return $query->where('product_id', '=', $id) }])->find($id);`

Comment: Thank you, maybe i wasn't clear so i edited the post. however, what i need is the suggested_product_id ->name

Comment: product_id on the product table is the same as in the suggested_products table, on my view of a single product i already have access to the data of a single product id. I want access to the name of a suggested_product_id

Comment: it's a collection relationship, try to `dd` the query result and see for yourself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the following relationship in your `Product` model:

```
public function suggestedProducts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'suggestedproducts', 'product_id', 'suggested_product_id')
                ->withPivot(['quantity', 'required']);
}
```

This would allow you to get all related products as Eloquent models by doing the following:

```
$product = Product::with('suggestedProducts')->find($id);

$product->suggestedProducts; // This accesses the suggested products
```

To access the name of each suggested product, just do the following:

```
foreach ($product->suggestedProducts as $suggestedProduct)
    echo $suggestedProduct->name;
```

To access the data in the pivot table, you have to use the following:

```
foreach ($product->suggestedProducts as $suggestedProduct)
    echo $suggestedProduct->pivot->quantity;
```

Comment: Thank you, thats works perfectly! care to explain the relationship part? or link a little docs? I'm still learning and want to take something more than just the answer away from this.

Comment: Yes sorry, you can actually find the documentation on this relationship at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Thanks, but its not exactly many-to-many its "product has many suggested products" reason being, that other products could have the same suggestion however each could suggest a different quantity. I expanded the table above to show this.

Comment: I understand what you mean but programmatically speaking it still is a many-to-many I would say. The only difference is that the relationship is both ways in the sense that when you have "product_id = 1" and "suggested_id = 2" in a row, you should have another row with "product_id = 2" and "suggested_id = 1". It's a bit weird but still a many-to-many.

Comment: Hi I noticed it broke something, I'm not able to get the quantity or required from the suggested products table in my foreach $suggestedproduct->quantity

Comment: @DevJustin Oh yes, you have to include the columns of the pivot in the relationship. I edited my answer :)

Comment: sorry to be a bug but it diddnt work, I'm not getting an error and its just not displaying in my table.

Comment: Edited my answer :) The doc about it is the "Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns" section in https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many